# How to extract OwnsOne as a Extension method in EF Core 5.0.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, extension-methods

I'm trying to extract 'ownsone' as an extension method for separate codes and placed in MyFramework and reuse mappings in all projects.

```
private static void SetSize(EntityTypeBuilder<GateRecord> builder)
{
    builder.OwnsOne(c => c.Container)
                .Property(x => x.Size)
                    .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<ContainerSize, int>
                    (
                        sizeId => sizeId.Id,
                        sizeId => Enumeration.GetBy<ContainerSize>(sizeId)
                    ))
                    .HasColumnName("SizeId");
}
```

And finally I have a problem sending these parameters( **c => c.Container** , **x => x.Size** , **<ContainerSize>** ).

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please be more specific. What problem do you have?

Comment: my problem is duplicate code in all project for all developers. I'm going to move this piece of code to the framework for all developers to use.

Comment: In fact, the bolded things should be passed to the function as a parameter, and I had trouble implementing it.

Comment: You can pass them as delegates, i.e. `Func<T, TOwned> owned`, but really you're just making it harder for your developers by wrapping the EF API at that point. That's why I wanted more details about the problem, you could show an example where the code is duplicated, because you may have options like extracting an interface

Comment: I have setSize / SetType / SetImoClass etc. in several micro services, so each developer has to repeat the code in each EFcore mapping.